# Problem loading large .RData file: Error reading from connection

Tags: r

I have an .RData file that is rather large. It takes up 1.10 GB on my hard drive, it contains a data frame with 100 variables and 12 million observations. Now when I try to load it, I can open the task manager and watch  the memory usage go all the way up to 7450 MB; at which point my RAM is completely exhausted, and I get "Error reading from connection." I'm pretty sure this memory deficiency is the problem, but how can that be? Like I said, the .RData is only 1.10 GB.

I'm using R x64 4.0.5. If it's any clue, when I open the 32-Bit version of R (4.0.5) it tells me "Error: memory exhausted (limit reached?)", reinforcing my suspicion that this is a memory issue.

I am unable to access the data any other way, I have to make the .RData file work or it's gone. Why does R require more than 8 GB of RAM to load a 1GB workspace?

Comment: `.Rdata` files are compressed as well as serialized, so 1.10GB is just its compressed size. I'm inferring that the file was created on a computer with more RAM, unfortunately I think there is very little you can do with "just" 8GB of RAM other than "buy more RAM". Option 1: If you can afford to work on subsets of the data, then go back to the original computer and split the data somehow into multiple `.Rdata` files, and work on only one at a time. Option 2: convert your process to use a SQL DBMS.

Comment: @r2evans isn't there a way to load the file in chunks? I have a 10GB file, and facing the same issue.

Comment: I know of no way to load *part* of an `.rda` or `.rds` file, though I am not the authority on their format. Your best bet for asking if that's possible is on [R-help or R-devel](https://www.r-project.org/mail.html). Lacking that, my suggestion to go back to the source and split the data into multiple `.rda` files is still a valid suggestion (and it may be your only recourse).